# Is there a way to define a compare function to issubset in Python

Tags: python, set

I want to use an approximate comparison to check if two sets are equal. 
More exactly, if there is a bijection of approximate elements on two sets.

As a toy example, consider the following function

```
def my_compare(a, b):
    ep = 0.1
    return a>=b-ep and a<=b+ep
```

I would like to do something like

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = {1.05, 2, 3}
c = {1.2, 2, 3}

print(a.issubset(b) and b.issubset(a))

print(a.issubset(c) and c.issubset(a))
```

Have output

```
True
False
```

PS: I know that I am subverting the mathematical definition of set by doing that. Even so. Is there?

Comment: So, you'd need create a wrapper class that defines an `__eq__` and `__hash__` methodcsome way... still thinking through the implications for `__hash__` though.

Answer (score 2):

To keep these comparisons efficient, you may want to consider an alternate underlying data structure, such as an Interval Tree.

The Python `portion` library at https://github.com/AlexandreDecan/portion could help you out here.

Define each element in the set as an interval sized `[x - 0.1, x + 0.1]`, and look for intersections between the two sets: https://github.com/AlexandreDecan/portion#interval-operations